# How to use ShowWIndow() and SetForegroundWindow Correctly?

Tags: python, win32gui, showwindow, setforegroundwindow

Here is what I want to do:

1)Open an application with username
2)Give some inputs
 
3)Open 2nd window for the application with different username
4)Give some inputs again
 
5)Switch to first application window, do somethg
6)Switch to second application

I am programming in python using the `win32gui` library.
I have tried using the `ShowWindow` and `SetForegroundWindow` , but it doesnt work correctly, can someone please explain me what would be the way to do it in a very simple way?

Comment: You need the window Handler to do that. Since you want to set other application's window to foreground, you might have trouble to find this Handler. Try to acquire it with `FindWindow`, that allows you to obtain a window Handle by it's title.

Comment: I have the handle for both the windows, but when I do ShowWindows(h1,3) then ShowWindow(h2,3) then again ShowWIndow(h1,3) it doesnt always work properly

Comment: Ok, when exactly are you using `SetForegroundWindow`? Because `ShowWindow(handle, 3)` only set a window to maximized state, it isn't implicit anywhere it will bring it to foreground.

Comment: Thanks for that heads up!!! I am either using SetForegroundWindow all the times or ShowWindow all the times, but its not working correctly in both cases. So just wanted to understand when to use which ?

Comment: You use `ShowWindow` to set its state after you create it or in case you want to hide/minimize/maximize it, and `SetForegroundWindow` when you want to bring it to front.

Answer (score -1):

Call `BringWindowToTop` and `SetActiveWindow` functions.